# Will restore via iTunes to iOS 15 from iOS 16 beta keep eSim working?

Tags: iphone, beta, ios16

Question in title. Don’t understand what they are actually hiding but Apple does not want to answer me about beta so I ask here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to restore my iPhone to ios 15.5 for some strange reasons. I was afraid that I might lost eSim. Fortunately, it did not happen. So, if we restore using iTunes also, eSim will be restored.